# `ffmpet -f concat` don't work when all input streams appear to have the same spec

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

My `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

My 1st input file:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\Applications\ffmpeg_6.0_full\a.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 27 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
```

My 2nd input file:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\Applications\ffmpeg_6.0_full\b.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2023-03-08T06:47:13.000000Z
    artist          : Microsoft Game DVR
    title           : PUBG: BATTLEGROUNDS
  Duration: 00:10:00.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 20885 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20739 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-08T06:47:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-03-08T06:47:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

The above command outputs some warning signals:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025239902d40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 00000252396fe5c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 218112, current: 150024; changing to 218113. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
...
a lot of them
...
frame=25992 fps=21754 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1519621kB time=00:14:49.39 bitrate=13996.8kbits/s speed= 744x
video:9649kB audio:1519216kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

The resultant video can play the first part of the video correctly, then the video players either skips directly to the end of the video (MPC-HC), or don't render anything at all while timer passes as normal (VLC).

My impression of the concat is that it requires all videos to have the same spec, which I think my input achieved (all the "Steam #0:0", etc, line matches). I only see the following difference, which I assumed that should be okay:

1. Metadata are different both for the whole input (e.g. "major_brand") and for each stream (e.g. "encoder"). I assumed that metadata won't affect the processing.
2. The order of video/audio streams are different in the two inputs: the 1st input file has audio then video; the 2nd input file has video then audio. I assumed that ffmpeg knows the difference and won't concat a video stream to an audio stream.

The full output of the command can be found in this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Z5q97Uyg

Comment: you can change order of streams: `ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy a_m.mp4`

Comment: Oh so the order of the v/a streams in an input does matter... Thanks for the suggestion. It worked by changing one of the input's v/a stream order.